# Auth0 is often requiring users to authenticate twice

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth, auth0

I have a client-facing web application built using Angular 7 that utilizes Auth0 (`auth0-js v9.8.2`) for authentication. We require users to login using username/password and then multi-factor using Guardian/text/phone call. All of this works great. The issue is that we are seeing that sometimes users are required to authenticate/multi-factor a second time immediately after they're redirected to the application from Auth0's hosted login page. I have seen it once or twice myself but now that I am trying to debug this issue I cannot replicate the issue. However, I see in the logs that several users per day are experiencing this inconvenience.

Here are some snippets from my code. If I knew how to replicate I would try and debug, but I can't even make it happen now, although it's still happening to others currently.

The first thing I'm doing in `app.component.ts` is calling `handleAuthentication()` and requiring users to authenticate if they're not already.

```
constructor(private auth: Auth, private dataService: DataService) {
    this.auth.handleAuthentication().then((res: any) => {
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            this.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            this.auth.auth0.authorize();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the `handleAuthentication()` function, which is resolved only once 'parseHash()' is called and the session is set.

```
public handleAuthentication(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.auth0.parseHash({ _idTokenVerification: false }, (err, authResult) => {
            if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
                window.location.hash = '';
                this.setSession(authResult);
            } else if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Here are my `auth0` settings in case it's helpful

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: '<domain>',
    clientID: '<clientID>',
    redirectUri: environment.callbackURL,
    audience: '<audience>',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    scope: 'openid'
});
```

My only guess is that it has something to do with 'parseHash()' failing. There are a couple of other things I find interesting.

1. In other examples, I don't see `{ _idTokenVerification: false }` being passed into `parseHash()`, but it was added for some reason at some point
2. I have seen others talk about issues with passing `id_token` into `responseType`, but we are using this token to check expiration. If this is could be causing an issue, I may be able to figure out a workaround

I can't just assume these are issues because I can't replicate the main issue with or without these modifications.

Any help or advice?